# Tell pyspark about known ordering

Tags: pyspark, data-partitioning

I have a huge dataset that includes a row_id, so I know that the row_id is monotonically increasing and that the data partitions are ordered by this row_id.

Now I want to shift some column using the lag() function:

```
window = sql.Window.partitionBy().orderBy('row_id')
df = df.withColumn('shifted_my_value', F.lag(df.my_value).over(window))
```

However, pyspark is not aware that the data is already ordered by row_id and wants to analyze/reshuffle the entire dataset (although I know that this would be a noop).

Is there a way to tell spark that my data is already ordered by row_id and it should just shift the values in my_values without trying to shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be just not ordering by a row in the window -

```
window = sql.Window.partitionBy().orderBy('select 1')
df = df.withColumn('shifted_my_value', F.lag(df.my_value).over(window))
```

I'm not sure in pyspark it will work like this or like that -

```
window = sql.Window.partitionBy().orderBy('(select 1)')
df = df.withColumn('shifted_my_value', F.lag(df.my_value).over(window))
```

In SQL it could work like that -

```
df.registerTempTable('df')
spark.sql('select LAG(df.my_value) OVER (order by (select 1)) FROM df' )
```

Comment: I'm afraid for the last command I get "AssertionError: col should be Column". The previous two complain that "select 1" is not a column.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `FROM df` in my sql query. It might work now.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, so I added it and it gave "AssertionError: col should be Column".

Comment: I am also wondering about the `partitionBy()` argument. If my dataset is huge, I cannot put all data into the same partition, right?

Comment: And are you sure that `select 1` really keeps the original ordering?